# Surround with suggestions from auto-complete in Intellij?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, ide

Suppose you have the following method

```
void consume(List<String> list) { ...
```

And somewhere you have, and want to call the method from above.

```
String sa = "whatever";
```

If you type:

`sa`

and then put the cursor before `sa` and want to autocomplete

`Collections.sing`|`sa` then <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> then <kbd>Enter</kbd>

what you'll get is

`Collections.singletonList()sa` and you want `Collections.singletonList(sa)`

Is there a way to automatically surround the variable with what auto-complete returns?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In mac it is <kbd>command</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>enter</kbd>

That will surround sa with the completed code.

That action is called complete current statement, <kbd>ctr</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>enter</kbd> on windows with the default keymap.

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly what you're looking for, but you can get a bit closer with [postfix completion](https://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2014/03/postfix-completion/). After typing `sa` and realizing that you want to call a method on it, you can type `.par`<kbd>Tab</kbd> to put the parenthesis around it, then <kbd>Home</kbd> to go back to the start of the line and you can type `Collections.sing`<kbd>Tab</kbd> to complete the method call.

That is, I think completion works the way you want if you put the parenthesis around the argument first. I'm not aware of a better way, though I'd be fine to be proven wrong.